# Residuals magnitude is larger than Seasonality magnitude after performing seasonal decomposition

Tags: time-series, seasonality

I'm working on the analysis of a dataset containing time series of hourly traffic congestion in a certain city, during a period of 23 years (number of data points: Roughly 24 X 365 X 23 = 201480).
I wanted to spot annual seasonality in the data, so I used:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

daily_avg_cong = df.groupby("Date")["Hourly_cong"].mean().reset_index()
ts = daily_avg_cong['Hourly_cong']
result = seasonal_decompose(ts, model='additive', period=365, extrapolate_trend='freq')
```

Trend and Seasonality seem to reflect the data properly - the trend shows the expected increase over the years, and the Seasonal component shows a cyclic pattern that is in line with what I would expect from observing the data.
My problem is the magnitude of the Residuals, especially compared to the Seasonal component. Residuals magnitude is 2-3 times more than the Seasonal component. Here's a plot of all the components:

[image]

If I understand correctly - the Seasonal component affects the time-series values less than the Residuals. Is this conclusion correct? Does that mean that fluctuations in traffic congestion due to noise are more "meaningful" than the annual pattern?

Thanks!

Edit: Following a suggestion by @brewmaster321, here's the hourly decomposition. I find it hard to interpret, would appreciate any kind of help with this. For example, I would have expected a smoother trend.

[image]

I'm adding one example of seasonal period since it's impossible to see on the main plot:

[image]

Edit #2: Following another suggestion by @brewmaster321, I used MSTL in order to decompose the different components, but the residuals/seasonality magnitude ratio doesn't seem to change much:
[image]

Seasonal components look OK when inspected on a smaller scale that allows seeing their periodic nature (each line represents 5 random years/weeks/days):

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm just guessing, but is it possible the magnitude of each seasonal component is not larger than residuals' magnitude, but I should actually look at the combined magnitude? This makes sense to me since each data point "contains" these 3 seasonal components. Again, shooting in the dark here and would appreciate any kind of help or guidance.

Comment: A quick look at this and it appears that your hypothesis is correct: fluctuations in congestion due to noise are bigger than your seasonal component. The other possibility is that seasonality is hourly rather than yearly - i.e. what do the plots look like if you use hourly as your period?

Comment: @brewmaster321 Thanks for the suggestion. I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 2):

So your traffic data will likely have multiple seasonalities, daily (period = 24), weekly (period = 24*7), and yearly. This is a good use case for MSTL:  https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/mstl_decomposition.html. If you remove all of these using something like:

```
   from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import MSTL
   stl_kwargs = {"seasonal_deg": 0} 
   mstl = MSTL(daily_avg_cong["Vehicles"], periods=(24, 24 * 7, 24*365), 
   stl_kwargs=stl_kwargs)
   res = mstl.fit()
```

You should end up with lower residuals than the totals of the seasonal components.